# WPF UserControl DataGrid Columns Binding C#

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, user-controls

I want to create an UserControl in WPF that has a DataGrid inside and I want to use it like I use a standard DataGrid.
For example, my UserControl appears like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SupervisoreIB.UI.CustomControls.DataGridWithHeader"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             ...
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Row="0">
            <Label Content="test" />
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="1">
            <DataGrid />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the way I want to use it is like this:

```
<uc:DataGridWithHeader Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10">
    <uc:DataGridWithHeader.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="COL1" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="COL2" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="COL3" />
    </uc:DataGridWithHeader.Columns>
</uc:DataGridWithHeader>
```

I tried to work with the Column DependencyProperty like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> Columns
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>)GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("Columns", typeof(ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>), typeof(DataGridWithHeader), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnColumnsChanged));
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the collection property in the constructor of the `UserControl`:

```
public partial class DataGridWithHeader : UserControl
{
    public DataGridWithHeader()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetValue(ColumnsProperty, new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>());
    }

    ...
}
```

Then you also need to populate the actual `DataGrid` with the columns in the callback, e.g.:

```
private static void OnColumnsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridWithHeader dataGridWithHeader = (DataGridWithHeader)d;
    dataGridWithHeader.dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
    if (dataGridWithHeader.Columns != null)
        foreach (DataGridColumn column in dataGridWithHeader.Columns)
            dataGridWithHeader.dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

Comment: or the collection could be initialized in the PropertyMetadata of Columns propdp